# how can i limit charging battery level at 60%

Tags: battery-life

Is there a way to limit battery charging to dedicated percent to conserve or store batteries, especially for built-in batteries, I have this feature in my Lenovo laptop but I can't find it in other laptops or in windows settings

Comment: This is likely a hardware feature of the charging circuit in your Lenovo device, and may not exist in other devices. I don't know of any such tools to control pattern charge %'age either physically or via software.

Comment: A battery is just a can of chemicals that begin to deteriorate on first use. Maintaining charge at 60% will not save the battery. The OEM Lenovo batteries are good for about 3 years

Comment: It’s most probably a Lenovo only feature, please go to the support website of your laptop manufacturer(the one in which you want the feature), they will help you with it.

Comment: this feature is found in lenovo and Asus laptop I think, but I think it is a software feature apple did something like that in charging batteries in ios 13 it takes longtime to charge from 80 to 100

Comment: could anyone help